# Slick Carousel stretching focus Image to full screen on Mobile Devices

Tags: jquery, mobile, carousel, slick.js

I set up my carousel using Ken Wheeler's Slick for my photography site.

I didn't want it to continue to run the carousel on a cellphone (or anything that small) so I set the entire section to display: hidden and then swapped it for a simple block display of the images (without carousel) at that screen size.  So, the Carousel is visible to anyone viewing at around 750 px or larger.  That part is fine.

Problem is, the Carousel runs perfectly on a desktop, but when I view it on my tablet, the options of slideToShow:3 aren't working.  Instead, the center Image (the one in focus) is stretched to fill the screen, warping the dimensions.

Not understanding why this would be operating differently in functionality than when looking at it on a desktop browser sized to the same width, but it is.  Again, it works perfectly as intended on a desktop.

My site is:

http://philippenewman.com/photography/sanfrancisco.html

Many thanks for any help that can be provided!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Slick Playground</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/slick/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/slick/slick-theme.css">

<!-- External Stylesheets-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- External Stylesheets-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--  Jquery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Stylesheets-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Stylesheets-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .slick-slide {
        margin: 0px 20px;
    }

    .slick-slide img {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 600px;
    }

    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

```
<!--BEGIN NAVBAR-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">philippe newman <span style="color:#99b3ff">photography</span></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Galleries <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="sanfrancisco.html">San Francisco</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">California</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="process_production.html">process + production</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!--END NAVBAR-->


<!--   BEGIN MAIN CONTENT HERE-->
<main class="main">

<!--       This section is for large tablet/Desktop views-->
    <section class="variable slider hidden-xs">
        <div>
            <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/caltrain_lights_9_7_2016.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/embarcadero_sunset_10_7_2016.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/golden_gate_bridge_dusk_10_10_2016.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/mission_st_alley_graffiti_san_francisco_8_26_2016.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/metreon_sf_intersection_night_8_13_2016.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/marshal_beach_sunset_second_10_19_2016.jps" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/cathedral_of_st_mary_san_francisco_7_20_2016.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/sf_windmill_night_9_30_2016.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/sutro_baths_sunset_second_shot_6_18_2016.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/seacliff_sunset_6_21_2016.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </section>

<!--        This section is for our mobile/tablet view only-->
    <section class="mobile-gallery hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 photo-row">
                    <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/caltrain_lights_9_7_2016_thumbnail.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 photo-row">
                    <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/embarcadero_sunset_10_7_2016_thumbnail.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 photo-row">
                    <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/golden_gate_bridge_dusk_10_10_2016_thumbnail.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 photo-row">
                    <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/mission_st_alley_graffiti_san_francisco_8_26_2016_thumbnail.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 photo-row">
                    <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/metreon_sf_intersection_night_8_13_2016_thumbnail.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 photo-row">
                    <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/marshal_beach_sunset_second_10_19_2016_thumbnail.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 photo-row">
                    <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/cathedral_of_st_mary_san_francisco_7_20_2016_thumbnail.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 photo-row">
                    <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/sf_windmill_night_9_30_2016_thumbnail.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 photo-row">
                    <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/sutro_baths_sunset_second_shot_6_18_2016_thumbnail.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 photo-row">
                    <img src="./images/photography/san_francisco/seacliff_sunset_6_21_2016_thumbnail.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--    JS file for Slick Scroller carousel-->
<script src="./js/slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function () {
        $(".variable").slick({
            infinite: true,
            variableWidth: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            draggable: true,
            centerMode: true,
            swipeToSlide: true
        });
    });
</script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what the issue may be?

Comment: Apologies!  Here it is:

Comment: Could you provide additional data about the tablet? Make and model, OS version & browser version. Debugging on owner name alone is not particularly efficient.

Comment: I'm using a Samsung Galaxy 4(?) Tablet (circa 2015 release)

Comment: Wow, I stumped the community.  Sad day.